# Shell icon not showing in Hue

Tags: hadoop, hue

My shell icon is not showing in the Hue browser. Does any one know how to enable it ? Googling does not provide many results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Several applications like the Shell app are probably not supported in this forked version of Hue 2.

You could look about how to install Hue 3 on http://gethue.com/hadoop-hue-3-on-hdp-installation-tutorial/